# Templated constructor ambiguity when calling overloaded function with castable type

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, overloading, overload-resolution

I have 2 classes that *both* have single-argument templated constructors. One is meant as a catch all for integer types, and in the other class it's for binding any iterable object. I have two overloads for a particular function that will each of these types. If I call the function with an integer type or a string, or something that would work for at least *one* of the classes, I get an error about call ambiguity.

```cpp
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    template <typename Iterable>
    A(Iterable it) : s(it.begin(), it.end()) {} 
private:
    std::string s;
};

class B {
public:
    template <typename Integer>
    B(Integer i) : i(i + 1) {}
private:
    int i;
};

void Use(A a)
{
   // some thing
}

void Use(B b)
{
    // some other thing
}

int main(void)
{
    Use(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler doesn't seem to be looking far enough into the set of polymorphisms to determine that there really only is one possible solution. Could this be because template are 'resolved' before function overloads? How do I give the compiler some help?

Comment: The name of a template argument is just a name. Naming something `Iteratable` means nothing for the compiler. Why don't you provide two arguments to constructor of `A` i.e. giving `begin` and `end` separately? A lot of std containers do it this way. (Plus: it would become more flexible to support sub-ranges of containers as well.)

Comment: You may also consider `std::begin()` and `std::end()`. This supports all containers with `begin()` and `end()` but beyond other things as well like e.g. plain C arrays.

Comment: "The compiler" does not look at the *body* of a function to determine if it can be called. And a good thing too, because such a thing would make software development in C++ rather chaotic.

Comment: Concepts of C++20 might helps, currently, SFINAE might help.

Comment: @n.m. I'm curious, why would it be chaotic?

Comment: Because any small mistake you make in a function template implementation *silently* invalidates it and selects a different overload. Go find your mistake now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The compiler doesn't seem to be looking far enough into the set of polymorphisms to determine that there really only is one possible solution.

Note that [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) is performed based on the signature of function templates, including function names, function parameters, template parameters, etc; but not implementations (e.g. the function body), which won't be examined during [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

You could apply [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to put restrictions on types which could be accepted by constructor templates, by adding another template parameter with default value. e.g.

```
template <typename Iterable, typename = std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<Iterable>().begin()),
                                                    decltype(std::declval<Iterable>().end())>>
A(Iterable it) : s(it.begin(), it.end()) {}
```

and

```
template <typename Integer, typename = std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<Integer>() + 1)>>
B(Integer i) : i(i + 1) {}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hJsJhrG9KOqP2GpJ)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't regard the implementation of the method when follows the SFINAE rules. In other words it sees the declaration of the class A constrator that accepts a single argument.

If you wish SFINAE to eliminate this choice, you need to move the expression that fails the substitution to the function signature.